# why does tomcat create a session cookie for every request?

Tags: jsp, session, tomcat, cookies

I'm developing a simple web app using JSP/servlets on Tomcat. 
I have an index.jsp page that presents the UI and loads JS code that makes repeated "polling" AJAX requests - simple stuff.

The problem is that each ajax request returns a new jsessionid, so data I'm trying to store in the session object is lost each time.

This problem does NOT occur on my dev machine where I am calling tomcat directly, it only happens in staging / live environment where requests go through Apache (on my dev machine I call localhost.../path/index.jsp and localhost.../path/ajax.jsp - in live env apache routes domain.com to domain.com/path/index.jsp and domain.com/ajax.jsp to domain.com/path/ajax.jsp)

I verified that I don't have useHttpOnly param or useCookies configured anywhere. We are using tomcat 6 BTW.

Could it be an apache-tomcat interaction issue?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2):

Could this be a problem with path of the cookies. Maybe session cookies are getting tied to domain.com/path. But from browser's point of view, path is domain.com/

Setting the cookie path to / would make browser to send cookies to domain.com/ as well.

Can you inspect cookies in Firebug / Fiddler and post the content here?

Answer (score 1):

> Unfortunately, the Servlet API is
> rather liberal in creating sessions.
> Various tools have default behaviors
> which can implicitly create sessions
> in the background. It's very easy for
> an application to "accidentally"
> create a session, even when one was
> not explicitly requested.
>
> An an example, JSPs will often create
> a session if one doesn't already
> exist. This allows JSPs to use the
> implicit session variable. As a second
> example, the request.getSession()
> method will also automatically create
> a session if one doesn't already
> exist.
>
> http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=191

i think the cause of the issue is explained above

Answer (score 0):

Try `<%@ page session="false" %>` at the top of index.jsp. If this does the trick then find another way to store the values (in request scope)